# When trying to use Python with C, I get error "unknown type name 'wctype_t'"

Tags: python, c, windows

So I was trying to run some Python code through a C file and the C file is just:

```
#include "C:\MinGW\mingw64\opt\include\python2.7\Python.h"

int main(){
    //any code
}
```

it comes up with the error:

```
"unknown type name 'wctype_t'" on lines 71, 72, 196, 197 on ctype.h and
expected ',' or ';' before wctype on line 159.
```

I searched it up but nothing came up.

My MinGW install is w64 with 8.1.0, x86_x64, posix and exception 'seh' and I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Please give a more fleshed out example instead of `//code` that causes the error you are asking about. It can be entirely contrived as long as it causes the error.

Comment: Just any code causes the error, it is in the #include "Python.h" bit

Comment: How did you get *Python* installed there? Please add the command you executed and the full output.

Comment: So if I copy/paste your code here with an empty main, then it will cause the error? If not, you should add some example code. Creating an [mcve] will help you get the answers you are looking for. Also, why Python 2.7? It is defunct.

Comment: I just typed python3 and it took me to the microsoft store to install it. I'm pretty sure it has the dev tools

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it causes the error with an empty main. I use python2.7 as it is the only folder which contains the Python.h file